# Subject Subscription in angular getting called twice for one next method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, redux, redux-observable

In Angular service i have created the subject and returning it as observable as follows :

```
  public entityPayLoad = new Subject<Entity>();

  public getSubjectAsObservable() {
    return this.entityPayLoad .asObservable();   

}
```

I am calling next method of subject from two different components as :


     From Comp 1 :

```
 this.Service.entityPayLoad.next(this.entity1);
```

From Comp 2 :

```
this.Service.entityPayLoad.next(this.entity2);
```

I am subscribing to subject as follows  which is getting called twice for one next method call:

```
this.entitiesSub = this.Service.getSubjectAsObservable().subscribe((entity) => {
            this.loadNewMainEntity(selectedMainEntity);
        });
```

> Initially it works fine, but after getting two next method call, then
>   for every subsequent one next request, subscriber gets called twice.

I have unsubscribed the same in ngondestroy.
But as i am not leaving the component for subsequent next call, unsubscribe does not get called.

Comment: where do your service provided in root?

Comment: @Asanka in provider section

Comment: yes in root (app.module) or in a sub module?

Comment: can u use behavioralSubject instead of subject and check?

Comment: @Asanka in app module